# Oracle: why doesn't use parallel execution?

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing

Look at the following query:
If I comment the subquery it uses parallel execution otherwise it doesn't.

After the query has been

```
SELECT  /*+ parallel(c, 20) */
      1, (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL)
  FROM DUAL c;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have found the answer [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm):

> A SELECT statement can be parallelized only if the following
>   conditions are satisfied:
>
> - The query includes a parallel hint specification (PARALLEL or
>     PARALLEL_INDEX) or the schema objects referred to in the query have a
>     PARALLEL declaration associated with them.
> - At least one of the tables specified in the query requires one of
>     the following:
>
>   - A full table scan
>   - An index range scan spanning multiple partitions
> - No scalar subqueries are in the SELECT list.

Your query falls at the final hurdle: it has a scalar subquery in its projection.  If you want to parallelize the query you need to find another way to write it.

Comment: Thanks! I've never realized this problem. Why Oracle doesn't use parallel with subqueries in the select list? Is there any logical reason?

Comment: @APC I think the manual is wrong here.  See my answer to the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9731552/409172

Answer (score 1):

One Idea could be not to use a subquery, but you can try and use a join? Your sub query seems fairly simply, no grouping etc, so it should not be an issue to translate it into a join.

Maybe the optimizer is not capable of parallel execution when there are subqueries.