# How do I parallelise a simple SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing

Say I have the classic:

`select * from employees where dob < to_date('10/10/1985', 'DD/MM/YYYY');`

The table is huge, so I want to parallelise this query.

Going by what I can see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c20paral.htm#13255

Essentially what we're wanting to do is arbitarily chop the table into n parts, and run our select statement on each chunk on a different thread, then join them together at the end.

1. Is parallelisation appropriate here?
2. How would I write the query?

Comment: You would just put an index on `dob` and let the engine figure out how to run the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is an index essential for parallel processing?

Comment: No.  But it is the most reasonable way to improve performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure. But given that I don't have admin privileges, that option's out.

Comment: Just a side issue, with long running parallel query, you might use up lot of resources, making the db slower.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ * from employees 
where dob < to_date('10/10/1985', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

See more from [Oracle Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#PFGRF94942).

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728558/oracle-is-there-any-logical-reason-not-to-use-parallel-execution-with-subquerie) to see why PARALLEL did not applied on your SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks Minh. This is what I thought the correct solution is. The trouble I'm having at the moment is ascertaining whether it's actually giving me an improvement.

Comment: Just need to try. It's the only way for performance tuning :)

Comment: When you say a full scan, do you mean a full scan by a single thread? or does breaking the table into chunks and having a full scan on each chunk count?

Comment: It means when you EXPLAIN_PLAN the sql, you have a "TABLE ACCESS FULL"  plan. This is simple to try, just run the SQL and see if it is improved?

Comment: The difficulty of course is: I can't see an explain plan on this table. And the performance of the DB is pretty sporadic, so simply running the query, it's ahrd to tell if it's a genuine improvement. But yeah, thanks for you help, it's stuff I can take back to email the DBAs with.

Comment: You CAN see an explain plan on SQL: run `EXPLAIN PLAN select /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ * from employees .......`

Comment: and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)` will query the plan table, after running `EXPLAIN PLAN`... `set pages 0` and `set linesize 4000` in `sqlplus` would make it read better.

Comment: The section of the manual you quoted is almost completely wrong - see my answer to a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9728558/409172).